# :!ls in vim closes the current file rather than open a window at the bottom

Tags: vim

When I use `:!ls` in Vim command line, it supposed to open a window at the bottom with  Press ENTER or type command to continue. But my vim closes the current file.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your desired behavior only happens in GVim/MacVim which comes with lightweight terminal emulation. When executed in your terminal emulator, Vim suspends itself and `ls` is run in the Vim's parent shell. `fg` is indeed the right way to get back to Vim.

Note that you can get a much more useful directory listing with Vim's buit-in Netrw plugin. Instead of `:!ls`, do `:Ex`.

See `:help netrw`.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use `fg` to go back to vim.